# Listen to a Node.js ReadableStream

Tags: node.js, stream, filestream

Is it possible to listen to a Node.js ReadableStream so I can, for instance, show a progress bar in the console as a file is being read?

In my particular case, another library is taking my ReadableStream: `fs.createReadStream(filePath)`. In the same vein, I want to watch this stream to see how much data has been moved through this library.

I was doing `stream.on('data', callback)`, but realized it was actually reading the stream. I'd rather listen for changes instead. I couldn't figure out how `pipe` would help me or any other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the [progress-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress-stream) package to do exactly what you asked for. 
if you are intrested in how you can implement this your self - check out the [github page](https://github.com/freeall/progress-stream) for the project and also look at these [resources](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html).